# Can't install packages while in secure FRP

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch

We are currently facing a challenging issue with Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 (sm-r860) / Samsung Galaxy Watch 5 (sm-r900) / Samsung Galaxy Watch 6 (sm-r930)after the recent update to WearOS 4.0. Our Mobile Device Management (MDM) system and Watch app, which worked seamlessly with WearOS 3.5, are now encountering difficulties in installing or updating the Watch app.

The error we consistently encounter is:

> Can't install packages while in secure FRP

Here's a summary of the problem and what we have tried so far:

**ADB Command:**

Using the ADB command

```
adb shell settings put secure secure_frp_mode 0
```

temporarily resolves the issue, but it's not a viable solution for us as it requires enabling Developer Options, which is not feasible for remote devices.

**DevicePolicyManager:**

```
mDevicePolicyManager.setGlobalSetting(mAdminComponentName, Settings.Secure.SECURE_FRP_MODE, "0")
mDevicePolicyManager.setSecureSetting(mAdminComponentName, Settings.Secure.SECURE_FRP_MODE, "0")
```

Attempted to change settings using mDevicePolicyManager, but encountered a security exception:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied: Device owners cannot update secure_frp_mode.

**FactoryResetProtectionPolicy:**

I explored the [FactoryResetProtectionPolicy API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/FactoryResetProtectionPolicy), but both the getFactoryResetProtectionPolicy and isFactoryResetProtectionEnabled methods return NULL. Setting the policy using setFactoryResetProtectionPolicy with `FactoryResetProtectionPolicy.Builder().setFactoryResetProtectionEnabled(false).build()` doesn't resolve the issue.

How can I resolve this issue within my MDM system?